# Multiple forms implementing recaptcha don't show the badge

Tags: angular, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

**Description**

I have implemented ng-recaptcha on an angular app.

**Scenario:**

Parent component has two child components both implementing recaptcha. Both the child components are within collapsible panels.

**Problem:**

Only when the 2nd component is activated via a collapsible panel the recaptcha badge shows up. When the 1st component is activated via the first collapsible panel the recaptcha gets hidden.

**Question:**

Is there way I can force the recaptcha badge to be displayed for the first component as well?

**Code Sample:**

```
 <re-captcha #recaptcha="reCaptcha" 
            size="invisible" 
            name="captcha" 
            [(ngModel)]="formModel.captcha" 
            required 
            (resolved)="$event && callMethod($event, 'Upload')">
</re-captcha>
```

**Lib versions:**

ng-recaptcha: 5.0.0

Angular: 9

Typescript (tsc --version): 3.8.3

**Posted on GitHub too -**

[GitHub - Multiple forms implementing recaptcha don't show the badge](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/179)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DethAriel](https://github.com/DethAriel) commented on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/179) on [Sep 12](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/179#issuecomment-691422726):

> Hi @siva-saripilli, and thank you for submitting the issue!
>
> From what I see, absence of the badge does not prevent recaptcha from
> functioning properly. Take a look at this example.
>
> Open the console tab in stackblitz and observe its output while you
> navigate from "Crisis Center" to "Login" -- invisible recaptcha is
> being executed properly, which is seen by the appropriate log
> statements.
>
> Now, I understand that the absence of the badge can be perceived as an
> inconvenience. However, the exact functionality of this badge is not
> controllable by ng-recaptcha library, I'm afraid -- it's part of core
> recaptcha functionality. Based on publicly available recaptcha API it
> doesn't appear to be controllable, so I'm afraid I have to close this
> issue as invalid.
>
> If, however, you find that this explanation does not represent the
> issue you observe, feel free to open a new bug with reproduction
> scenario attached.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently by default only one badge is displayed.  Refer to [GitHub - Multiple forms implementing recaptcha don't show the badge](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/179)

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless

Comment: Thank you @AmirhosseinYari Good point.  Will do that!